# How to create block in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

how to create a block or what is the alternate of the below code

`Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setData('area', 'frontend')->setTemplate('template.phtml');`

I am searching inside `Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface` Not pretty sure that I am on right side. can someone help sorting this.

Also I'm looking for some cheat sheet/ quickies that provide the alternate of mostly used methods and functions of Magento 1 to Magento 2.